# URL Rewriting and save end of URL as variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using url rewriting to have artists/(artistname) go to artists/index.php?(artistname).

I use this code to do the url rewriting

```
RewriteRule    ^artists/(.+)$    artists/index.php?$1
```

I then use this code to get the part of the URL after the ? and save it as a variable

```
$pageURL = 'http';
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
$artist = parse_url($pageURL,  PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

That code works when I don't use the URL rewriting, but not when I use it. I have checked it by echoing $artist. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: What's the output for `$artist` when you assign it the value for `parse_url($pageURL, PHP_URL_PATH);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite rule needs to be fixed. It looks like your rule could cause a redirect loop, this should result in a server 500 error, surprised that it doesn't. Try something more like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/artists/index.php.*
RewriteRule ^artists/(.+)$    artists/index.php?$1 [L]
```

The conditional statement should eliminate a the rule from looping.  Additionally add the [L] flag to the rule to stop the rule from processing more at that point.

Comment: so I should just add the condition right before it, and wouldn't the L  stop other rewrite rules that I have after it

Comment: [L] only stops if it's a match, unless you want that "specific" rule to potentially match any other rules, [L] is suggested (and it will speed up load times so your not continuously checking other rules)

Answer (score 0):

Because your new Rewrite rule, gets rid off the params your `parse_url` for the Url querys wont work. You can try instead:

```
$artist = basename(parse_url($pageURL,  PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different way to get the URL that worked

```
$artist = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$artist = substr($artist, 9, -1);
```

Comment: Michael, did you try modifying the .htaccess rule as in my post below?

Comment: it was working without your post, but your suggestion makes sense to stop a loop from occuring