# Get data from webpage url without $_GET

Tags: php

So I want to be able to set up a single PHP script that can handle requests to unique urls. In this case, the user is submitting a join id code. For example, with `$_GET` they could go to `example.com/join?code=abc123` and I could easily get the code with `$_GET['code']` which would be set to "abc123". However, I want to set up a system where they can join with a url like the following: `example.com/join/abc123`. I do not know how to get the `abc123` code from that url. I want all of this to be handled from a single script, ex. `join.php`.

Comment: If you want to pull `abc123` from it, then use `parse_url()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Zach, your question's a tad bit unclear. You want to pull `abc123` but use a mod rewrite, correct? Pretty sure that's what you need here then.

Comment: I have the mod rewrite all set up so that I remove the `.php`, but I am still unclear of how to pull the `abc123`

Comment: `parse_url()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19193610/  could be of help and other answers in the same question. TBH, I'm not so hot with `.htaccess` stuff.

Comment: I understand how the `parse_url()` function works but I am unclear where I would put the code that uses that function. If I go to `example.com/join/abc123` it is going to give me a 404 error. How would I be able to put the code in `example.com/join` so that I could get all the data after `/join/` in a single file, if that makes sense

Comment: What exactly is your problem? if you think its mod-rewrite related then why don't you post the code?

Comment: It is not mod-rewrite related (I think).

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php Thanks for the help